# invalid v token expires twitter sharekit

Tags: objective-c, xcode, twitter, sharekit

I am using sharekit to share url from my xcode app. I am getting `Invalid V Token expires` and can not able to share link. any idea about this? Consider am testing on simulator and previously it was worked fine but now it through an error like this. I have tried after resetting keys as well ..no luck

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Twitter. Twitter OAuth tokens never expire.

Comment: Air-dex, I did not say it is related to twitter, I was saying that when I want to share link on twitter using sharekit I am getting this error..